# deque push back error

Tags: c++, deque

I am writing a compiler and use deque to store methods labels of a class and here's the sample code:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::deque;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
  deque<const char *> names;

  string prefix = "___";
  const char *classname = "Point";

  const char *methodname[] = {"Init", "PrintBoth", "PrintSelf", "equals"};

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      string label = prefix + classname + "." + methodname[i];
      names.push_back(label.c_str());
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cout << names[i] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

However, the result is not what I've expected:

```
___Point
___Point.PrintSelf
___Point.PrintSelf
___Point.equals
```

Also, I noticed if I simply push back the methodname

```
names.push_back(methodname[i])
```

I get all the methodnames in order.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  string label = prefix + classname + "." + methodname[i];
  names.push_back(label.c_str()); //what you're pushing? a temporary!

} //<--- `label` is destroyed here and it's memory is freed.
```

Here `label` is a variable which gets destroyed at the closing brace and gets created again, in each iteration.

That means, what you're pushing to `names` is a temporary value. That is causing the problem.

I would suggest you to use this:

```
std::deque<std::string> names;
```

then do this:

```
names.push_back(label); //a copy is pushed to the deque!
```

Comment: so the pointer returned by label.c_str() points to a place within the storage space of label?

Comment: @manuzhang: Yeah. What `label.c_str()` returns is a pointer managed by `label`. So when `label` is destroyed, the memory it manages is freed.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the `string label` is a temporary, and its chhar pointer isn't valid once it exit the scope - the for loop, in this case.

I suggest to use `deque<string>` instead. this way you can push `label` itself, and then a real copy of `label` will be created inside the deque.